# CakePHP paginator not paginating

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have a paginator as follows:

```
    var $paginate = array(
        'order'=>array('ReleaseServer.server_environment'=>'ASC',
                           'ReleaseServer.server_name'=>'ASC'),
        'joins'=>array(
            array(
                'table' => 'release_server_to_components',
                'alias' => 'ReleaseServerToComponent',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions'=> array('ReleaseServer.id = ReleaseServerToComponent.release_server_id')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'release_components',
                'alias' => 'ReleaseComponent',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions'=> array('ReleaseServerToComponent.release_component_id = ReleaseComponent.id')
            )
        ),
        'group'=>array('ReleaseServer.id'),
        'contain' => array(
                'ReleaseServerToComponent' => array(
                        'ReleaseComponent' => array(
                            'Release'
                            )
                        )
                ),
        'limit' => 25,
    );
```

Then in my controller function I do the following:

```
$this->set('allServers', $this->paginate('ReleaseServer', $conditions));
```

Where `$conditions` are some extra conditions for the query.

As you see above I set the limit at 25.

There are 29 records in the database however, but the page only shows 25 and the page says there is only one page.

**but** when a person clicks on one of the column headers to order them, some rows that were not there before magically appear, and others disappear.  Why would this be?

If you need any other info please let me know

**UPDATE**

Now i see that the problem resides in the `group` part of the `paginate` variable, but i need it in order to make it so I do not get multiple rows of the same thing.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a new `paginateCount()` function to my model:

```
function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array())
{
     $count = $this->find('count', array(
        'fields' => 'DISTINCT ReleaseServer.id',
        'conditions' => $conditions
    ));
    return $count;
}
```